# creation of view with dynamic Model in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am new **Asp.Net Mvc** . I am doing a sample application for **Blogging** . I tried to create **Partial view**  for **Archives** for categorizing **Post** according to **date** .

```
Month/Year(count)
  Post 1
  Post 2
Month/Year(count)
  Post 1
  Post 2
```

In Controller

```
[ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Archives()
    {
        var post = from p in db.Posts
                   group p by new { Month =p.Date.Month, Year = p.Date.Year } into d
                   select new { Month = d.Key.Month , Year = d.Key.Year , count = d.Key.Count(), PostList = d};

        return PartialView(post);
    }
```

Please help me write View for this Action with this Month, Year , Count and collection of Post .

Comment: @downvote is my question wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

You may be struggling because you are passing an anonymous type into your View. I would create a `ViewModel` to represent your type;

```
public class Archive
{
  public string Month { get; set; }
  public string Year { get; set; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
  public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}
```

and then change your action to use the type;

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Archives()
{
  var post = from p in db.Posts
    group p by new { Month =p.Date.Month, Year = p.Date.Year } into d
    select new Archive { Month = d.Key.Month , Year = d.Key.Year, Count = d.Key.Count(),
      PostList = d };

    return PartialView(post);
}
```

and then you can strongly type your view to the `Archive` class;

```
@model IEnumerable<Archive>

@foreach (Archive archive in Model)
{
  <h2>
    @archive.Month / @archive.Year
  </h2>
}
```

Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Matt